# how to create pdf file with table in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

i'm looking pdf library with MIT licence to create simple pdf file with table in VB.NET.

iTextSharp is very good option but it's not for free to comercial use

Comment: This question is likely off topic for this site, but [PDFsharp and MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net) are MIT licensed and may give you what you want.  You can also find the old iTextSharp v4.1.6 which was LGPL licensed in various places (including [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/)).

Answer (score 0):

i checked PDFsharp and is very difficult to create table in vb.net or my vb.net skills are shittly.

Comment: how to setup padding in PDFsharp ?

Comment: and how to add image in PDFsharp ?